# Prove the subring test (in subtraction closure form)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S\subseteq R$. Prove *$S$ passes subring test iff $S$ passes  ideal test*

---

Ideal Test (for $S$) $ $ [**beware** this does not test if $S$ is an ideal  - see comments / answers - Bill D.]

1. $S\neq \emptyset $
2. If $x,y \in S \Rightarrow $ $xy\in S$ and $x-y\in S$

Subring test

1. Closed add $\forall x,y \in S \Rightarrow x+y \in S$
2. Closed mult $\forall x,y \in S \Rightarrow x*y \in S$
3. $\exists 0_R \in S$ $\hspace{3mm}$ $\forall x \in S, \exists x:0_R+x=x $
4. Additive inverses   $\hspace{3mm}$ $\forall x \in S, \exists  
                                                             -x:0_R=x+(-x) $
   $\hspace{3mm}$ $\forall y \in S, \exists  
                                                         -y:0_R=y+(-y) $

---

**Proof**

$\Rightarrow ]$ ( $S$ passed Subring Test $\Rightarrow$ $S$ passes Ideal Test )

Assume $S$ is a subring

*(we need to show that $S\neq \emptyset$ and If $x,y \in S \Rightarrow $ $xy\in S$ and $x-y\in S$.)*

**$(S \neq \emptyset)$** $S$ is a subring so $\exists 0_R \in S$ so $S \neq \emptyset$
$$

(If $x,y \in S \Rightarrow $ $xy\in S$ and $x-y\in S$)

Assume $x,y\in S$ Since $S$ it is a subring it is closed under multiplication so $x*y \in S$

Now, Since $x,y\in S$ where $S$ is a subring then  $\exists -x ,-y \in S $
Also, S is closed under addition so $$\forall x,-y \Rightarrow x-y \in S $$

$\Leftarrow ]$ (S has passed Ideal test  $\Rightarrow$ S passed Subring test)

**Showing $\exists 0_r \in S$.**

$S\neq \emptyset$ so $\exists $ an element call it $a\in S$ using (2) on Ideal test set a=b, a=a So $\forall a\in S$ s.t  $a-a=0_S\in S$

**Showing $\exists $ additive inverse**

use (2) on Ideal test Set $a=0_S$ $b=a$ so $0_s-a=-a\in S$

**Closed under add**

$\forall a,b \in S$ we have stablished that $-a,-b \in S$. Now using $\forall,b \in S:a-b\in S$ set $a=a,b=-b$ so $$a-(-b)=a+b \in S$$

**Closed under mult carries straight over**

---

When Starting to write my thoughts I was not sure how to solve it. But things came together.Still,  I appreciate any constructive critique. and do I do a mistake??

---

There are [link1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11373/relationship-between-subrings-and-ideals) [link2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500212/show-that-ideal-is-a-subring?rq=1) related to this problem. But does looks like an English essay. Also they ask about *relation* and is not the iff statements just implies.

Comment: YOu could call the first one an "abbreviated subring test," but "ideal test" is a bad because it doesn't check to see if it is an ideal. You aren't checking for absorption you see.

Comment: @Hugo Do you know the difference between ideals and subrings?

Comment: @rschwieb  also slade. ok I see. It is not an ideal because of absorption. got confused becuase it is almost  looks like Ideal def. I I don't need to show it is an Ideal just that those properties hold.  I'll fix that in my head. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Slade There's an $x-y$ in the second condition which precludes the $\Bbb N\subseteq \Bbb Z$ example.

Comment: @AndrewDudzik It would be best t delete your prior comment to avoid confusing beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written seems to all be correct. The only apparent problem is that the first batch of conditions is misnamed. It leads the reader to believe that it checks for a subset to be an ideal, when actually it is just an abbreviated list of axioms for a subring.

To make a valid test for an ideal, you could switch it to this:

> Ideal Test (for $S$)
>
> 1. $S\neq \emptyset $
> 2. If $x,y \in S \Rightarrow $ and $x-y\in S$
> 3. If $x\in S$ and $y\in R$, then $xy,yx\in S$.

As you can see, it is strictly stronger than the first set of conditions you gave.