# Ideals and proper unital subrings : $I \subset A \subsetneq B$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I have two questions, just the  first one remains unsolved for me.

1. Is there an example of a commutative unital ring $B$, a **unital** subring $A \subsetneq B$ and a non-zero ideal $I$ of $B$ such that $I \subseteq A$?
2. Let $A \subset B$ be two commutative rings. Assume that any proper ideal of $A$ is also an ideal of $B$. Do we have $A=B$ ?

I noticed that $2)$ is wrong if we assume that any proper ideal of $B$ is included in (thus an ideal of) $A$; take $B$ to be a field. Actually, I've just noticed that $2)$ is wrong: take $A$ to be any field.

For $1)$ I thought to $B=\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z \supsetneq A = \{(x,x),x\in \Bbb Z\}$. But it didn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: must the unit be the same for the two rings?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo : yes, sorry. I should have said "subring" (which means same unit element for me).

Comment: but $A$ is not a subring

Comment: I've found it : try $I=A=\{p(x)\in B\mid p(0)=0\} \subset B=\Bbb R[x]$. :-)

Comment: Actually my comment above is wrong (I've taken it from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/11378 but there "subring" doesn't have to contain 1). Here also (https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/determine-whether-a-subring-is-an-ideal/) there is an answer : take $B$ the ring of all functions from the closed interval [0,1] to $\mathbb{R}$, and $I=A$ the set of all functions f(x) such that f(q) = 0 for all $q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$. But A doesn't contain 1.

Comment: If $A=\mathbb Z+X\mathbb Q[X]$ and $B=\mathbb Q[X]$, then $X\mathbb Q[X]$ is a common ideal.

Comment: @AlexM. : If $I$ is included in $A$, then $I$ is an ideal of $A$, since $I$ is an ideal of the ring $B$, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Alphonse yes, $I$ is certainly an ideal of $A$ in this case.

Comment: @user26857 : Thank you very much for the example $I = X \Bbb Q[X] \subset A=\Bbb Z+X\Bbb Q[X] \subset B=\Bbb Q[X]$, this is really helpful !

Comment: @Watson I've lost the point of the parallel conversation, but your link it's about  the idealization of a module. Is this related to the present question?

Comment: @Alphonse yeah haha I moticed it was incorrect but you deleted too soon. plz dont delete interesting question in the future

Comment: @Alphonse: In fact, **user26857**'s example gives us the following general scheme: if $S \le B$ are two unital commutative rings, and if $I \subset B$ is a proper ideal, then let $A = S + I$.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo : yes, sorry, I will avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R, S$ be commutative unital rings and let $S' \le S$ be a commutative unital subring. Let $A = R \times S'$ and $B = R \times S$. Clearly $A \le B$ and $(1,1) \in A$. If $I \subset R$ is a proper ideal, then $I \times \{0\} \subset A$ is a proper ideal too.

---

(Alternatively, following [@user26857's excellent suggestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092249/ideals-and-proper-unital-subrings-i-subset-a-subsetneq-b?noredirect=1#comment4302581_2092249), one may start with $B$ and consider a unital subring $S$; then $A = S + I$ is a unital subring as desired.)